# Изменить значение option jQuery select2

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить значение выбранного option в select.

```js
function select() {
  $("#type").val("3");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<input class="mybtn" type="button" onclick="select();" value="GO">
<select id="type" class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно например так. Код меняет как значения атрибута `value` выбранного `option` так и текст

```js
$(".mybtn").on('click', function(){
  $("#type option:selected").val("3");
  $("#type option:selected").text("3");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="mybtn" value="GO">
<select id="type">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

И не пишите вот так: `onclick="select();"`

Comment: с select2 указанный код работать не будет...

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Изначально в постановке вопроса, и слова о `select2` не было )

Comment: Как тогда изменить значение?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').val('two').trigger('change');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7srqrxxu/16/

Answer (score 0):

Я так задавал уникальные классы для select2.
Но есть новая и старая версия select2, этот код от старой версии вроде как. Если скачать последнюю версию, не будет работать скорее всего

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    theme: 'default уникальный-класс-который-будет-именно-этого-select'
});
```